# How to use free scales but keep a fixed reference point in ggplot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot with facets. Each facet should have its own scale, but for ease of visualization I would like each facet to show a fixed y point. Is this possible with ggplot?

This is an example using the `mtcars` dataset. I plot the weight (wg) as a function of the number of miles per gallon (mpg). The facets represent the number of cylinders of each car. As you can see, I would like the y scales to vary across facets, but still have a reference point (3, in the example) at the same height across facets. Any suggestions?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() +
geom_hline (yintercept=3, colour="red", lty=6, lwd=1) +
facet_wrap( ~ cyl, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

[EDIT: in my **actual** data, the fixed reference point should be at y = 0. I used y = 3 in the example above because 0 didn't make sense for the range of the data points in the example]

Comment: Isn't your request against the notion of free scale?

Comment: That's a good question :) I think that I still want a free scale (I want the space in the plot to be distributed differently for each facet), but I would like to have a fixed reference point to help the reader. This is a mock example: in my data, the reference point is actually 0, so centering all facets at 0 makes more conceptual sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unclear where the line should be, let's assume in the middle; you could compute limits outside ggplot, and add a dummy layer to set the scales,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
# data frame where 3 is the middle
# 3 = (min + max) /2
dummy <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, 
               min = 6 - max(wt),
               max = 6 - min(wt))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point() +
  geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(y=min, x=Inf)) +
  geom_blank(data=dummy, aes(y=max, x=Inf)) +
  geom_hline (yintercept=3, colour="red", lty=6, lwd=1) +
  facet_wrap( ~ cyl, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]